# DevOps Build Can't Find NetCore.App when building for .Net 5

Tags: azure-devops, msbuild, azure-functions, .net-5, c#-9.0

I'm trying to run a devops build for dotnet 5 for the first time.

Here's my build pipeline:

```
variables:
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Debug'
  projects: '**/Interfaces.Avaloq.BamApi.AzFunc.csproj'
stages:
  - stage: A
    pool:
            name: Hosted Windows 2019 with VS2019
            demands:
            - msbuild
            - visualstudio
    jobs:
      - job: Build
        continueOnError: true
        steps:
        - task: UseDotNet@2
          displayName: 'Install .Net Core SDK'
          inputs:
            packageType: 'sdk'
            version: '5.0.100'
        - script: |
        - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
          displayName: Restore Functions
          inputs:
            command: restore
            projects: '$(projects)'
            feedsToUse: config
            nugetConfigPath: nuget.config
        - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
          displayName: Build Functions
          inputs:
            command: build
            projects: '$(projects)'
            arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'
        
        - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
          displayName: Publish
          inputs:
            command: publish
            arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --output $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
            projects: '$(projects)'
            publishWebProjects: false
            zipAfterPublish: true
```

And this is the cs proj it attempts to build "Interfaces.Avaloq.BamApi.AzFunc.csproj":

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v3</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.0.7" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

The dotnet restore works ok but for the build task I get the following error:

> Error : It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
> The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '3.0.0' was not found.
>
> - The following frameworks were found:
>   5.0.0 at [C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]

I can't see why it's trying to find v3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems Azure Functions won't support dotnet 5 until end of 2020. Details here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/6674